# How to convert SQL Filter to Pyspark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following SQL :

```
freecourse_info_step_8 as (
-- How many questions answered correct in that
select *, 
    count(question_number) FILTER (WHERE answered = true) over(partition by hacker_rank_id, freecourse_version, question_block, freecourse_users_id) as answered_correct_in_block
from freecourse_info_step_7
),
```

I converted to Pyspark as

```
column_list = ["hacker_rank_id", "freecourse_version", "question_block", "freecourse_users_id"]
window = Window.partitionBy([f.col(x) for x in column_list])
freecourse_info_step_8 = freecourse_info_step_7.withColumn('answered_correct_in_block',
                                                           f.when(f.col('answered') == True, f.count('question_number').over(window)))
```

I suspect that the code does not have the same behaviour as the SQL.
Am I right? How could I convert this SQL to PySpark correctly?

Pyspark spark.sql() method does not work with FILTER

Answer (score 0):

```
freecourse_info_step_8 = freecourse_info_step_7.withColumn('answered_correct_in_block',
                                                          f.count(f.when(f.col('answered') == True, 'question_number')).over(window))
```

the count function should be outside the when coditional